# Map over json data : how to insert label?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, dictionary

Suppose i have json data like this :

```
{
"siteCode": "S01",
"modelCode": "M001",
"modelDesc": "Desc01",
"price": 100
"status": "A",
"startDate": "May  6 2023  4:13PM",
"endDate": "May  6 2023  4:13PM"
},
{
"siteCode": "S01",
"modelCode": "M001",
"modelDesc": "Desc01",
"price": 50
"status": "A",
"startDate": "May  10 2023  4:13PM",
"endDate": "May  10 2023  4:13PM"
}
```

And required format is as follow

```
{Catalogues : [
  {
  "siteCode": "S01",
  "modelCode": "M001",
  "modelDesc": "Desc01",
  "datelist": [
    {
    "price": 100
    "status": "A",
    "startDate": "May  6 2023  4:13PM",
    "endDate": "May  6 2023  4:13PM"
    },
    {
    "price": 50
    "status": "A",
    "startDate": "May  10 2023  4:13PM",
    "endDate": "May  10 2023  4:13PM"
    }
  ]
  }
]
}
```

This is the code

```
 const data = result.recordset

 const map = new Map(data.map(({ siteCode, modelCode, modelDesc }) =>
       [modelCode, { siteCode, modelCode, modelDesc, datelist: [], }]
       ));
       for (const { siteCode, modelCode, modelDesc, ...rest } of data) {
       map.get(modelCode).datelist.push(rest)
       };
       const resultMap = [...map.values()];
       return res.json(resultMap)
```

which result minus label `{Catalogues : [`

How to add/insert label 'Catalogues' as above or what is the correct way to generate those format?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by wrapping the resultMap in an object with the "Catalogues" key before returning the JSON response.
For example:

```
const data = result.recordset;

const map = new Map(data.map(({ siteCode, modelCode, modelDesc }) =>
  [modelCode, { siteCode, modelCode, modelDesc, datelist: [], }]
));

for (const { siteCode, modelCode, modelDesc, ...rest } of data) {
  map.get(modelCode).datelist.push(rest);
};

const resultMap = [...map.values()];

// Wrap the resultMap in an object with the "Catalogues" key
const resultWithLabel = {
  Catalogues: resultMap
};

return res.json(resultWithLabel);
```

Comment: aha its working :)